# How to find all nonnegative integers $x, y, z$ and $w$ such that $2^x3^y-5^z7^w=1$

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic, algebraic-equations

> Find all nonnegative integers $x, y, z$ and $w$ such that $2^x3^y-5^z7^w=1.$

I think they are $(x,y,z,w)=(1,0,0,0),(1,1,1,0),(3,0,0,1),(2,2,1,1)$, but I couldn't prove its sufficiency (or there may be other solutions).

Does anybody have a good (or elegant) solution to this?

(**Be careful that $x,y,z,w$ are "nonnegative integers",.**)

Comment: What did you try to prove that there are no other solutions?

Comment: Why must it be a very easy problem if $x,y,z,w$ are assumed to be natural numbers?

Comment: "What did you try to prove that there are no other solutions?" Sorry, I don't get what you mean.

Comment: @AlonAmit Well exactly, "a very easy" must be a hype. To explain it is a little difficult so please don't care about it, I was careless.

Comment: @user8507985 Have you tried anything to prove that there aren't other solutions (or to find others)?

Comment: @CarlSchildkraut Yes I've been trying to and it seems that there aren't any other solution but I couldn't prove it.

Comment: @user8507985 What sorts of things have you been trying?

Comment: @CarlSchildkraut Put the equations of d=0, c=0,... into WolframAlpha to solve them over the integers, but if I've tried to solve b,c,d≠0(we know that a≠0), its computing time has come over. And I don't know other things to do.

Comment: Where did you come across this problem?

Comment: @CarlSchildkraut My friend sent it to me.

Comment: 100% sure it's from a competition. The question is which.

Comment: @barto Do you know what competiton it is from? I'm not familiar with such things.

Comment: For a solution, see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2381171 and https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h24692p155821. Similar questions: https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h1274704p6678076, https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h405620p2263995

Answer (score 5):

One possible solution is as follows: you're looking for two consecutive numbers where all prime factors are 7 or less.  The list of numbers $n$ such that $n$ and $n+1$ have all their prime factors 7 or less is finite, and can be found [at OEIS](https://oeis.org/A085153); it's

1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 14, 15, 20, 24, 27, 35, 48, 49, 63, 80, 125, 224, 2400, 4374.

The fact that this sequence is finite is [Størmer's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/St%C3%B8rmer%27s_theorem), which also provides an algorithm for finding the list.

Furthermore, you want a number in this sequence, $n = 5^z 7^w$, with prime factors 5 and 7, such that $n + 1$ only has prime factors 2 and 3.  The numbers in this sequence with prime factors 5 and 7 only are (by inspection):

1, 5, 7, 35, 49, 125

Adding 1 to each of these, you can see that 2, 6, 8, 36 have prime factors 2 and 3 only, while 50 and 126 do not.  So the only solutions are $n = 1, 5, 7, 35$ which correspond to your four solutions.

Answer (score -1):

Imagine all are bigger than 0, also, imagine x is bigger than 2. then modulo 8 $((-3)^z)((-1)^w)+1=0$ Then, given that z is odd because of mod 3, we get that in either case, be it w even or odd there is a contradiction, so x is either 1 or 2.

Be it 1, modulo 7 we find there should be this modularity pairs (x,y) = (3m, 6k) (3m+1,6k+4) (3m+2,6k+2), and modulo 5 we find they are (4u,4t) (4u+1,4t+1) (4u+2,4t+2) (4u+3,4t+3). So we get a contradiction brcause then 6k+4=4t+1. Imagine then x=2. Then, if both z and w are 2 or more, modulo 25 we get y=60Q+14 and modulo 49 we get y=42m+21 wich is a contradiction, so both z and w can not be both 2 or more.

We now have bounds so the rest is casework